# Getting the number of reduce tasks operating at the moment

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, amazon-dynamodb, hadoop-streaming

I'm using Amazon AWS, Dynamo DB, and EMR cluster for hadoop streaming. My reduce tasks write to a Dynamo table. I need to establish and adhere to an upper bound on writing to the table, say at 50% of the write throughput.

I can query the table's write throughput setting, divide by mapred.reduce.tasks, and multiply by 50% to get the lower bound on write throughput to the table for each task. Even better, I want to query the number of reduce tasks being worked on *at the moment* to get an exact write throughput upper bound for each reduce task, but I don't know how to get that number. I see it in the jobtracker where it shows total number of tasks, tasks pending, and tasks being worked on.

One alternative, not as flexible, is to set the number of tasks using hadoop streaming parameter "-numReduceTasks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `JobTracker` API for this as described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ClusterStatus.html).

In particular, you are interested in calling `getClusterStatus` which will return you a `ClusterStatus` object detailed [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ClusterStatus.html). From then it's simply a matter of calling `getReduceTasks` which will give you the number of currently running reduce tasks in the cluster.

You could also get by using the `getClusterMetrics` method which gives you similar information.